# How to Display Depth and Color Images Simultaneously Using Kinect Viewer SDK Python Wrapper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azurekinect

I'm currently working with the Kinect Viewer SDK and its Python wrapper for a project. I've noticed that the SDK provides previews for various modes, including infrared, depth, and color images. However, I'm having trouble displaying the depth and color images simultaneously using the Python wrapper.

I've attempted to use the same Device class instance to achieve this, but it doesn't seem to be supported. Additionally, while I've looked through the documentation, it's unclear whether achieving this functionality is possible with the Python wrapper, as Python isn't the official language for Azure.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to display both the depth and color images together using the Kinect Viewer SDK Python wrapper? Any examples or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.